# How can I remove the None or set the good status for a celery task?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

Hello when I launch a celery task I got that for instance :

```
[2021-09-22 22:11:26,878: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task Todos.celery.launchalert[886eb5a6-66cf-4759-a208-7245aca9882b] succeeded in 26.386354280999512s: None
```

If the task is ok or have errors I got None and succeeded ... How can I do to either remove that either show the right logs ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What is the code of your task? Is it returning anything?